# Angular Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: angular, frontend, migration

I have faced the this issue, and I still haven't resolved it.

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):        
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

[image]

Comment: you may have circular dependency in your code/ used npm packages

Answer (score 0):

You might have an infinite loop in your code, causing the stack to fill up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).